# Java File Object for a File in ADLS Gen2

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a tool that works for on-premise data upload. Basically, it reads the file from local system i.e.(on-premise: Linux or Windows) and send it over to a location.
It makes use of Java File class. eg: new File("/dir/file.txt")

I want to make use of the same code for input files on ADLS Gen2. I would be running the code on Azure Databricks and stuck with getting the File object for the files in ADLS Gen2. I am using wasbs protocol for making the File object, but it is coming as null as Java is not recognizing the directory structure.

Comment: Could you please share the complete stack trace of the error message which you are experiencing along with code which you are running on Azure Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

If this tool is using local file access, then you can still use it by [mounting the ADLS as DBFS to some location](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html), like, `/mnt`, and then use this mount locally as `/dbfs/<mount-point>` (`/dbfs/mnt/`).